# How do I prevent a procedure from executing when an invalid input value is entered?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have created two tables: `workouts.session` and `workouts.exercises`.

I have created a stored procedure to enter workout sessions into the log. However, I could not figure out how to prevent a user from entering invalid or incomplete data. How should I change my code? For instance, I need SQL to throw an error when a user enters invalid exercise id, or when all entries are null.

Tried different things, but everything failed. Believe I must add a transaction statement, and raiseerror statement. Tried different things, but I do not have enough experience with this :(

Original code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Workouts.AddSession
    @SessionDate datetime,
    @Exercise_ID int,
    @Weight_Time int,
    @Unit char(7),
    @Reps int,
    @Set int,
    @RestSeconds int,
    @Comment char(256)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO workouts.Session (SessionDate, Exercise_ID, Weight_Time, 
                                  Unit, Reps, "Set", Comment)
    VALUES (@SessionDate, @Exercise_ID, @Weight_Time, 
            @Unit, @Reps, @Set, @RestSeconds, @Comment)
END
```

Comment: use `IF` and check for your required conditions. Something like `IF @Exercise_ID IS NULL RAISERROR(. . .)`

Comment: use [EXISTS()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to check for existence of  `ID` in the table

Comment: Thank you @Squirrel I will try that. Tried similar thing before but not familiar with that function yet, so I failed... Only learned about stored procedures today and syntax seems a little different for me.

Comment: You list **7** columns in your `INSERT INTO` statement - but you then go on to provide **8** values .....

Comment: Using `If` and `RaIsError` or `Throw` is a good start for input validation. You might want to wrap the `Insert` in a [`Try ... Catch`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) so that you can handle errors that result from the `Insert` failing. Defending against "bad" data starts with the design, e.g. don't store a `bit` as `'Y'` or `'N'` in an `NChar` because someone will put in `'⅜'`. Constraints provide a way to handle range checks, e.g. valid values for `Unit`. Relations handle checks against other tables. And triggers.

Answer (score 0):

To answer as close as possible to your question, I recommend try-transaction block with `raiserror`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Workouts.AddSession
    @SessionDate datetime,
    @Exercise_ID int,
    @Weight_Time int,
    @Unit char(7),
    @Reps int,
    @Set int,
    @RestSeconds int,
    @Comment char(256)
AS
BEGIN

set xact_abort on
begin try
    begin transaction
    -- start business here
    
    if @Excercise_ID not in (5,7,8 /*...valid ids here....*/) 
        raiserror('Exercise_ID %i is invalid',16,0,@Exercise_ID)
        
    if @Weight_Time is null and @Unit is null and @Reps is null and......
        raiserror('All gym parameters are null',16,0)
        
    INSERT INTO workouts.Session (SessionDate, Exercise_ID, Weight_Time, 
                                  Unit, Reps, "Set", Comment)
    VALUES (@SessionDate, @Exercise_ID, @Weight_Time, 
            @Unit, @Reps, @Set, @RestSeconds, @Comment)
    
    -- end business here
    commit
end try
begin catch
    if @@trancount > 0 rollback
    declare @rethrow nvarchar(4000)='Error >> num '+convert(nvarchar(max),error_number())+', line '+convert(nvarchar(max),error_line())+', message: '+error_message()
    raiserror(@rethrow, 16, 0)
end catch
```

However, you have to think if the stuff of your question apply not only to this procedure, but to the table `workouts.Session` **regardless** of source. In that case, in order to ensure data integrity, you should use constraints instead.

Making sure no set of columns are all-null can be done with a `CHECK CONSTRAINT`:

```
alter table workouts.Session add constraint CHK__WORKOUTS_SESSION__NOT_ALL_NULL CHECK(not (Weight_Time is NULL asnd Unit is NULL and Reps is NULL and ....))
```

CHK__WORKOUTS_SESSION__NOT_ALL_NULL is just the constraint's name, use whatever you want. Using a prefix like CHK is a good idea

About having valid Exercise_ID, you can do this with a check constraint too. Same syntax as above, but instead `CHECK(Exercise_ID in (5,6,7....))`

Notice that, unlike the same check in the procedure, in a check constraint you can **not** use another table for the `IN` clause. The best way for valid values is to have a master table with Exercise_ID as primary key, have all possible values there, then add a `FOREIGN KEY` there:

```
alter table workouts.Session add constraint FK__WORKOUTS_SESSION__EXERCISE_ID__REF__OTHERTABLE__ID
foreign key(Exercise_ID) references othertable(id)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help! I now see what I was doing wrong. Must enter conditions first and then state what I am inserting. This makes sense now. Well, actually I've already referenced the foreign key when I was creating this table. At the time I was not sure what it does, but now it is clear. Tried to run my procedure today by entering an invalid ID and it failed. So, good on this part, but now I know how to set up more constrains. Thank you so much! I will definitely practice this syntax.